# Issue with reading user input in Java (Delimiter/Pattern issue)

Tags: java, string, exception

This program takes input from the user in the form of a vector `<xcoord,ycoord>`. I have successfully got the buffer from the user.

I've debugged this and found out the `.hasNext()` part of this isn't detecting the first `<` in my code and it outputs the `"Missing the first arrow"` exception. Any help on this?

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Vector Calculator!"); //display messages to the user'
    System.out.println("Please enter your vector"); //display messages to the user'
    Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in); //first scanner
    String commandLine = userInputScanner.nextLine(); //buffer is read in correctly
    userInputScanner.close();
    VectorCalculator.parseVectorString(commandLine); //parse vector string and print out values.**
    }
}
```

Then to this method (important code commented with ****):

```
public boolean read(String commandLine) throws Exception {

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(commandLine); // ****

     Pattern originalPattern = scanner.delimiter(); //retain original delimiters for scanner
     scanner.useDelimiter("[" + originalPattern + ",]"); // add comma to delimiters
     scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
     if(scanner.hasNext("<")){ //
         scanner.next("<"); //gobble up the '<'
         if(scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
             xCoord = scanner.nextDouble(); //capture the x coordinate
             //scanner.useDelimiter(originalPattern); //restore original delimiters
             if(scanner.hasNext(",")){
                 scanner.next(","); //gobble up the comma
                 if(scanner.hasNextDouble()){
                     yCoord = scanner.nextDouble(); //capture the y coordinate
                     //scanner.useDelimiter(originalPattern); //restore original delimiters
                     if(scanner.hasNext(">")){
                         scanner.next(">");
                         scanner.close();
                         return true;
                     } else {
                         scanner.close();
                         throw new Exception("Missing the end arrow");
                     }
                 } else {
                     scanner.close();
                     throw new Exception("Missing the y coord");
                 }
             } else {
                 scanner.close();
                 throw new Exception("Missing the middle comma");
             }
         } else {
             scanner.close();
             throw new Exception("Missing the x coord");
         }
     } else {
         scanner.close();
         throw new Exception("Missing the first arrow");
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't do `userInputScanner.close();` - this will also close the underlying `System.in`, preventing any further possibility of getting input

Comment: I'd also consider making use of regular expression capture groups, something like `<(\d*\.?\d*),( )?(\d*\.?\d*)>` as a rudimentary/rough starting point

Comment: I'd also make use of [try-catch-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) rather then relying on all the `if-else` statements

Comment: Thank you for the help, I also think I might've neglected to mention that the scanner buffer is empty (""), I'm really not sure if it's a delimiter issue or

Comment: Honestly, I don't think `Scanner`, in this case, is the best choice, but's just my opinion

Answer (score 0):

> *'... This program takes input from the user in the form of a vector `<xcoord,ycoord>`. ...'*

If the parse is simple enough, just use *String* methods.

Here is an example.

```java
String s = "<1, 2>";
int n = s.length() - 1, i;
if (s.charAt(0) != '<') throw new Exception("Missing the first arrow");
if (s.charAt(n) != '>') throw new Exception("Missing the end arrow");
s = s.substring(1, n);
if ((i = s.indexOf(',')) == -1) throw new Exception("Missing the middle comma");
if (s.lastIndexOf(',') != i) throw new Exception("Extra comma");
String[] v = s.split(", +");
if (v[0].isEmpty()) throw new Exception("Missing the x coord");
if (v[1].isEmpty()) throw new Exception("Missing the y coord");

System.out.println("s = " + s);
System.out.println("v[0] = " + v[0].trim());
System.out.println("v[1] = " + v[1].trim());
```

Output

```
s = 1, 2
v[0] = 1
v[1] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the **Scanner#useDelimiter()** is really what you want to use for this sort of thing. You are expecting the User to enter in vector data then you want to validate that entry to ensure it is in the correct format. If it isn't then provide a relatively detailed reason why it's not valid.

To be honest, entry mistakes will always be done especially if it involves more that one character but, the User will have far greater success with his/her entries if....they know exactly what they are expected to enter. Throw the User a bone and let them know before you toss out a prompt like: `"Please enter your vector"`. You would find that if an entry error is made, then just an `Invalid Entry! (34.4, 55.1>) - Try again...` message should pretty much suffice. The User can see exactly where the problem is and then make a correct attempt.

To validate the a User's entry, the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method can be used along with a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex), for *example*:

```
String commandLine = "";
while (commandLine.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your vector data (q to quit): -> ");
    commandLine = userInputScanner.nextLine().trim();

    /* Validate Entry - If the entry does NOT match the regex 
       then inform User and allow him/her to try again.    */
    if (!commandLine.matches("^(\\<(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),\\s?(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\>)$")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Vector Entry Supplied! (" + commandLine + ") - Try again..." );
        commandLine = "";  // Empty `commandLine` to ensure re-loop.
    }
}
VectorCoordinate vc = VectorCalculator.parseVectorString(commandLine);
```

**What does the regex passed to the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method mean?**

- `^` Asserts position at start of the String;
- `\\<` The first literal character must be the Less-Than (<) character;
- `(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)` Next must be a string representation of a signed
  or unsigned Integer or Floating Point value;
- `,` The supplied numerical value must be followed by a comma (,);
- `\\s?` The comma may or may not be followed by a single white-space;
- `(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)` The comma (or comma + white-space) must be followed by a string
  representation of a signed or unsigned Integer or Floating Point
  value;
- `\\>` The last literal character must be the Greater-Than (>)
  character;
- `$` Asserts position at the end of the String.

Below is a runnable which *similarly* puts the above code into practice. The application consists of three classes, the **MainStartClass** class, the **VectorCalculator** class, and the **VectoCoordinate** class. The User supplied Vector data is placed into an instance of VectorCoordinate which will hold the `x` and `y` coordintes supplied. The User can continuously supply vector coordinates until 'q' for quit is entered. All VectorCoordinate instances are stored within a List Interface of VectorCoordinate which can be displayed when the User quits. Please be sure to read all the comments in code:

---

**The MainStartClass class:**

```
public class MainStartClass {

    /**
     * First (and ONLY) Scanner object for `System.in`:<br>
     * Do Not close this resource unless you are absolutely sure
     * you will not need it again during your application run. If
     * you do, you will need to restart your application in order
     * to use `System.in` again. The JVM will automatically close 
     * this resource when the application ends. This object can be 
     * used globally:                 
    */
    public final static java.util.Scanner userInputScanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 
    
    /**
     * A List Interface object of VectorCoordinate to store 
     * valid User supplied vector data: (see VectorCoordinate
     * class). This object can be used globally:   
    */
    public static java.util.List<VectorCoordinate> coordsList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    
    /**
     * Not all Terminal or Console windows utilize the same newline 
     * character sequence. This ensures that the `newline` character 
     * sequence complies with the Operating System this application 
     * is run in. This object can be used globally: 
     */
    public static final String LS = System.lineSeparator();
    
    
    // Application entry point:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need for statics 
           (unless we actually want them):        */
        new MainStartClass().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        /* Inform what application is about. Give Users a fighting chance
           towards a proper entry. Let them know what is expected of them:  */
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Vector Calculator:" + LS 
                         + "=================================" + LS
                         + "You will be prompted to enter vector data which will ultimately" + LS 
                         + "get parsed into X and Y Coordinates. All supplied coordinates" + LS 
                         + "are to be enclosed within Chevron Brackets (< >) and delimited" + LS 
                         + "with a comma (,). Both Integer and or Floating Point values can" + LS 
                         + "be supplied. The Integer values will be auto-converted to double" + LS 
                         + "type. Here is an example entry: -  <26, 67.8>" + LS 
                         + "----------------------------------------------------------------" + LS); 
        
        // Prompt #1 - Prompt for User to enter in Vector data:
        String commandLine = "";
        
        // Continually ask User for vector data unless 'q' was supplied to quit:
        while (commandLine.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your vector data (q to quit): -> "); 
            commandLine = userInputScanner.nextLine().trim(); 
            
            // Was 'q' supplied to quit?
            if (commandLine.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                // Is quit really desired (see the `quit()` method)?
                if(!quit()) {
                    // No...Empty `commandLine` so to ensure re-loop:
                    commandLine = "";
                }
                // Otherwise...
                continue; // Because `commandLine` is not empty, this will exit the `while` loop
            }
            
            /* Parse the supplied vector string and print out values.
               If `vc` does not equal null, then the User entry is valid 
               and is stored as `VectorCoordinate` (see the VectorCoordinate 
               Class - Also see the `VectorCalculator` class `parseVectorString()`
               method):                                               */
            VectorCoordinate vc = VectorCalculator.parseVectorString(commandLine); 
            if (vc != null) {
                coordsList.add(vc);  // Add valid entry to List.
                System.out.println("X Coordinate = " + vc.getX() + "  |  Y Coordinate = " + vc.getY());
            }
            // Otherwise...
            commandLine = "";       // Empty `commandLine` so to ensure re-loop.
            System.out.println();   // Display a blank line for aesthetics.
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * This method prompts the User to ensure that he/she truly wants to 
     * quit the application. 
     * <p>
     * If `n` (no) is supplied, then boolean false is returned and this 
     * then gets interpreted that quit is not desired and the application 
     * continues to prompt for, and accept, Vector entries.
     * <p>
     * If `y` (yes) is supplied then the User is confronted with yet 
     * another prompt which asks if he/she wants to display the stored 
     * Vector entries. If at this point `n` (no) is supplied then the 
     * application will simply return boolean true which is later interpreted 
     * as a desire to quit. If however, `y` (yes) is supplied, then 
     * the User is displayed all the stored vector entries and then the 
     * application simply returns true which is also later interpreted as 
     * a desire to quit.<br><br>
     * 
     * @return (boolean) 
     */
    private boolean quit() {
        boolean res = false;
        // Prompt #2 - Prompt for `Are You Sure...`:
        String yn = "";
        while (yn.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Are you sure you want to quit (y/n)? -> ");
            yn = userInputScanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (!yn.matches("(?i)[yn]")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid Entry Response! Try again..." + LS);
                yn = "";
            }
        }
        if (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            // Prompt #3 - Prompt to display store Vector entries but only if there are any: 
            yn = "";
            while (yn.isEmpty() && !coordsList.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print("Do you want to display all User Entered Vectors first? -> ");
                yn = userInputScanner.nextLine().trim();
                if (!yn.matches("(?i)[yn]")) {
                    System.err.println("Invalid Entry Response! Try again..." + LS);
                    yn = "";
                }
            }
            if (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.println(LS + "Vectors Entered By User:" + LS +
                                        "------------------------");
                for (VectorCoordinate c : coordsList) {
                    System.out.printf("X = %-10s Y = %-10s%n", c.getX(), c.getY());
                }
                System.out.println("------------------------");
            }
            System.out.println(LS + "Quiting - Bye Bye." + LS);
            res = true;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

**The VectorCalculator class:**

```
/**
 * Used for validating and parsing supplied vector coordinate strings
 * from User.
 */
public class VectorCalculator {

    /**
     * Used for validating and parsing supplied vector coordinate strings.<br><br>
     * 
     * @param commandLine (String) Vector data in the format: {@code "<n, n>"}.<br>
     * @return 
     */
    public static VectorCoordinate parseVectorString(String commandLine) {
        double x = 0.0d;    // To hold the Vector X Coordinate:
        double y = 0.0d;    // To hold the Vector Y Coordinate:
        
        /* Validate supplied commandLine string:
           Is the supplied string in `commandLine` valid?     */
        if (!commandLine.matches("^(\\<(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),\\s?(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\>)$")) {
            // No... Determine what is wrong with it and display that info:
            /* Copy commandLine into `cl` but first, remove any possible double 
               (or more) white-spacing from within the vector string and make 
               them single spaced. Also trim of any leading or trailing white-
            spaces:                    */
            String cl = commandLine.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
            
            // Prepare for error messaging. All errors found are concantenated together:
            StringBuilder errMsg = new StringBuilder("");
            
            // Is the supplied vector string empty?
            if (cl.isEmpty()) { errMsg.append("The supplied Vector string can not be empty! "); }
            
            // If the supplied string doesn't start with the '<' character:
            if (!cl.startsWith("<")) { errMsg.append("Missing Opening Bracket (<)! "); }
            
            // If the supplied string doesn't end with the '>' character:
            if (!cl.endsWith(">")) { errMsg.append("Missing Closing Bracket (>)! "); }
            
            // Remove the brackets from the suppliec vector string:
            cl = cl.replaceAll("[<>]", "");
            
            // If the current vector string does not contain a comma (,).
            if (!cl.contains(",")) { errMsg.append("Missing comma (,) delimiter between coordinates! "); }
            
            // Otherwise...split the coordinate values and validate them:
            else {
                /* Split the coordinate values based on a comma delimter 
                   and 0 to unlimited number of spaces after the comma.  */
                String[] coords = cl.split(",\\s*");
                
                // If the length of coords = 0 then no coordinate values were supplied!
                if (coords.length == 0) { errMsg.append("Missing the X/Y Coordinates!"); }
                
                // If the length of coords = 1 then there was no `y` coordinate value supplied!
                else if (coords.length == 1) { errMsg.append("Missing the Y Coordinate!"); }
                
                // If `coords[0]` is empty then there is no `x` coordinate value supplied!
                else if (coords[0].isEmpty()) { errMsg.append("Missing the X Coordinate!"); }
            }
            
            // Inform User of all the problems and return `null`:
            System.err.println("Vector Parse Error! - Invalid Vector Data Supplied (" 
                               + commandLine + ")! - " + errMsg.toString());
            return null;
        }
        
        // Yes...The supplied Vector String appears to be valid!
        /* Remove the brackets (using the `String#substring()` method) 
           and split the coordinate values into a String[] arrays based 
           on a comma delimter and 0 to unlimited number of spaces after 
           the comma (if any):               */
        String[] xy_coords = commandLine.substring(1, commandLine.length() - 1).split(",\\s*");
        
         /* Convert the above array x and y coordinate string numerical values 
            to double type values:           */
        x = Double.parseDouble(xy_coords[0]);
        y = Double.parseDouble(xy_coords[1]);
        
        // Create a new VectorCoordinate and return it.
        return new VectorCoordinate(x, y);
    }
}
```

**The VectorCoordinate class:**

```
public class VectorCoordinate {
    
    double x;
    double y;
    
    /**
     * There are no Setters for `x` and `y`, only Getters. Typical setting of 
     * `x` and `y` would be through this constructor.<br><br>
     * 
     * @param x (double)
     * 
     * @param y (double)
     */
    public VectorCoordinate(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.x + ", " + this.y;
    }
}
```